# FluentFuture Class not found with multiple AnntationProcessor

Tags: java, maven, code-generation, dagger-2, annotation-processor

I am developing a simple Java 8 project with Maven and a custom AnnotationProcessor.

If I use only the [Dagger 2](https://github.com/google/dagger).15 or my AnnotationProcessor, it works well, but If I use both of them, maven build will fails with the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project MyProject: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FluentFuture: com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture -> [Help 1]`

I tried to import `com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture` class from `com.google.guava.guava` repository (version r05, 19.0, 24.1-jre), but it has not worked.

Project structure:

- There is a Maven project, what contains the annotations, and two AnnotationProcessors (one of them validates only, the other generates source code) (Based on [this](https://deors.wordpress.com/2011/09/26/annotation-types/) article)
- There is another Maven project, what uses this project as a dependency. In that I would like to use Dagger 2 for dependency injection (I imported it just like it is in the description in Dagger 2 page).

What can I do?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I downgraded to dagger 2.14.1 and stopped getting that error.

Comment: It is fixed the original error, but I got an other one:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) on project TTT: Fatal error compiling: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator; -> [Help 1]`

Can you suggest anything? (guava not helps :( )